# How to type responses for Visual Studio Code (Python)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How do you interact with code for programs like "What is the temperature" and type it into a window? My code just goes to output window, which can't be typed in.

New to coding/visual studio and not sure how to get an interactive window.

[image]

Comment: Just click on the terminal window and type your response, should work.

Answer (score 3):

`Code Runner` does not support `type in` in the `OUTPUT` panel. You can choose `Run Python File in Terminal` to execute the python file.

[image]

And you can configure the `Code Runner` to avoid this problem too, add this in the settings.json file:

```
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
```

Comment: @Crimson Have you solved the problem? if this is helpful, could you accept this answer? thanks, and have a good day : ).